# Minimum number of terms to approximate $\pi=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, approximation, pi

Consider the Leibniz formula for $\pi$
$$
\pi=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}.
$$
What is the minimum number of terms needed to calculate $\pi$ accurate to $k$ decimal places?

**My attempt:** Let's consider $k=2$ decimal places for example and set $a_n=\frac{4}{2n-1}$. One way to think about this is to consider the remainder of the series and simply use
$$
|R_n|\leq a_{n+1}\Leftrightarrow |R_n|\leq \frac{4}{2n+1}\leq 10^{-2}
$$
which holds for $n\geq 200$. Alternatively, [Calabrese's error bound](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.08568.pdf) yields
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{2} < |R_n| < \frac{a_n}{2}\Leftrightarrow \frac{2}{2n+1} < |R_n| < \frac{2}{2n-1}
$$
which leads to $99.5<n<100.5$ and thus $n=100$, a refined number. Indeed, either term order satisfies
$$
\begin{align}
R_{200}&=4\sum_{n=201}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}\simeq 0.004999968751 \leq 10^{-2}\\
R_{100}&=4\sum_{n=101}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}\simeq 0.009999750031 \leq 10^{-2}
\end{align}
$$
However, the partial sums give
$$
\begin{align}
S_{200}&=4\sum_{n=1}^{200}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}\simeq 3.136592685\\
S_{100}&=4\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}\simeq 3.131592904
\end{align}
$$
which are not accurate to two decimal places ($\pi\simeq 3.14...$). In fact, the minimum value of $n$ I found (computationally) that gives an accuracy to two decimal places was $n=119$. Indeed,
$$
\begin{align}
S_{119}&=4\sum_{n=1}^{119}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}\simeq 3.149995867\\
R_{119}&=4\sum_{n=120}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}\simeq -0.008403213004
\end{align}
$$
Is there an analytical way of determining the minimum number of terms for any accuracy $k$?

**Comment:** Out of curiosity, I have calculated the first $10$ minima for "accuracies" $k=0,...,9$. Respectively, I got
$$
(3,19,119,167,10794,136121,1530012,18660304,155973051,1700659132)
$$
On a log plot, we get

[image]

Comment: Maybe the arctangent Maclaurin series [error bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127829/bound-for-error-term-in-taylor-expansion-of-arctan-x) helps.

Comment: I imagine the answer that occurs to most people who first try it is "more than I thought".

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does this question from? Out of curiosity? Or an actual course?

Comment: @BrianTung Pure curiosity. Bounds for the remainder or error are often discussed in courses, but not the minimum number of terms, so I wondered whether this was achievable.

Comment: When you want a number that is accurate to 2 decimal places, you don't want to make the error below $1/100$: numbers can be within $1/100$ while not having the same digit in the hundredths place. Try making the error less than $.5/100$, or more simply less than $1/1000$ (at the cost of more terms), not less than $1/100$.

Comment: I don't think it is realistic to expect to get the *minimal* number of terms needed by some tidy rule. Ultimately an error bound is only saying that by going a certain amount into the series you're sure to be within a certain distance of the limit, and the first time a certain digit matches what is in the limit is a more delicate thing than that.

Comment: So the 50th term is  $\frac{1}{99}$ followed by $\frac{1}{101}$ There difference is roughly $\frac{1}{100^2}$, so that means it effects mostly the 4th digit. More generally,  $(2n-1)^2/>10^{k+1}$. So $n \approx [(10^{(k+1)/2} +1)]/2$ So if $k=8$, $n \approx 15811$

Comment: As others have pointed out, obtaining a number of correct digits can't be done analytically because it depends crucially on the next digit. For example, getting a prefix of $3.1415$ *for the first time* will happen relatively quickly because you can have an error of more than $9$ in the next digit (on the low side). But the last time you get a prefix of something *other than* $3.1415$ will happen quite later, because you need an error less than $1$ in the next digit (on the high side).

Comment: A more reasonable target is to get asymptotic number of terms needed to get within an error of $\varepsilon$. The $(2k-1)$th and $2k$th terms are $+1/(4k-3)$ and $-1/(4k-1)$, and $\pi$ is roughly halfway between the corresponding partial sums as $k$ gets large, so the error would be about half the absolute value of those terms, or approximately $1/(8k)$. So you're looking for about $k = 1/(8\varepsilon)$ to get an error of $\varepsilon$. (Assuming I didn't miss a factor of $2$ somewhere—hardly a foregone conclusion.)

Comment: My second-to-last comment is why you saw such a big jump between $167$ and $10\,794$.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed: The problem with that approach is that the difference between $\pi$ itself and either the $50$th or the $51$st partial sum is on the order of $1/200$, not $1/100^2$. Even though the effect of those two terms is only to add about $1/100^2$, it's purely additive, as is the effect of the next two terms (approximately $1/102^2$, and the next two terms (approximately $1/104^2$), and so forth. Those add up, and the effect in the long term is approximately $1/200$.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt the problem can be solved precisely. But some estimates can be obtained. Let's focus on the approximation from below. We have $$4\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}=4\sum_{k=1}^n\left ({1\over 4k-3}-{1\over 4k-1}\right )\\ =8\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(4k-3)(4k-1)}
$$
The error is less than the $(2n+1)$th term of the original series i.e. $4/(4n+1).$ The actual error $E$ is equal $$8\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{(4k-3)(4k-1)}>8\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{(4k-3)(4k-1)}>{8n\over (8n-3)(8n-1)}>{1\over 8n}$$ Thus
$${1\over 8n}<E<{1\over n}$$ Hence if we want the error $E$ satisfies $10^{-N-1}<E< 10^{-N}$ we need  $$ 10^N\le  n\le 10^{N+1}/8$$ Similar analysis can be made for approximation from below.

Comment: This is super interesting, thank you! Could this be somehow used to determine the number of terms needed to guarantee no change in the $k$th decimal place? Please see this [follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4831035/approximating-pi-4-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n-12n-1).

Answer (score 1):

It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80#Unusual_behaviour) that the remainder in the Leibniz series possesses an asymptotic expansion of the form
$$
\left| {\pi  - 4\sum\limits_{k = 1}^N {\frac{{( - 1)^{k - 1} }}{{2k - 1}}} } \right| \sim \frac{1}{N} - \frac{1}{{4N^3 }} + \frac{5}{{16N^5 }} -  \ldots 
$$
as $N\to +\infty$. Assume that
$$
\left| {\pi  - 4\sum\limits_{k = 1}^N {\frac{{( - 1)^{k - 1} }}{{2k - 1}}} } \right| = \varepsilon 
$$
for some small $\varepsilon>0$. Then by series reversion
$$
\frac{1}{N} \sim \varepsilon  + \frac{1}{4}\varepsilon ^3  - \frac{1}{8}\varepsilon ^5  +  \ldots ,
$$
and thus
$$
N \sim \frac{1}{\varepsilon } - \frac{1}{4}\varepsilon  + \frac{3}{{16}}\varepsilon ^3  +  \ldots 
$$ as $\varepsilon \to 0^+$.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4216465) might also be of interest for you.